# Locked out of Steam - not getting passcode email

Tags: steam

My firewall was blocking Steam while I was logging in and failing. Now I am locked out of Steam and need an access code to log in. There seems to be no way to tell the Steam servers to send this code and I didn't get one in my email anywhere (checked all folders and searched for "`steam`").

I sent Support an email but haven't got a response in over a day now. This seems like an incredibly easy thing to fix if they could just send an email with the code.

Is there really nothing else I can do except just wait an unknown amount of time until my ticket is finally seen?

---

Edit: Steam support was useless, took 4 days, and only reset my password which I could already do and did. They clearly didn't read the ticket info I provided because I stated that.. clearly. They did not resend the Steam Guard pass-code and as of now it is simply disabled. Not sure whether I will be able to log in or get it working if I do re-enable it.

Comment: It sounds like your Steam e-mail address may not be what you think it is... unfortunately I'm not sure how you would check that.

Comment: I thought that also, but I have the steam verified email address email and the secure link to their site verifying said email which now fails because I already did it.

Comment: The email would have been sent, perhaps try another machine or ask for the code to be sent again. It is extremely rare for a machine to make an error, more likely human error on some part. Also, remember any time difference for Steam HQ.

Comment: Are you talking about a Steam Guard email?

Comment: I'll try a different computer. Yeah the Steam Guard email I gather.

Comment: Did not work on another computer.

Comment: If your email provider offers the option of checking which IPs have accessed your email account, check that. Maybe somebody stole your account.

Comment: Interesting prospect, I'll look into it.

Comment: Account is not stolen as I am able to reset/change the password and did so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one way to regain access is to reset your password. If Steam Guard did make some server-side error, password reset emails should be unaffected. Once one arrives, reset your password to the same one (Steam doesn't check for previously-used passwords) and that will bypass Steam Guard. Once you're in, try disabling and re-enabling Steam Guard from Steam's settings. Then try logging out and back in to make sure Steam Guard emails are now sent.

Comment: The author's problem isn't connect to Steam Guard.

Comment: Great suggestion but even after I reset my password, I still can't log in without the access code.

Comment: Turns out one of my machines *was* able to log in and I could disable steam guard from in there.

Answer (score 3):

The "access from new computer" email is always sent instantly in my experience. Check the spam filter and verify that you are definitely checking the correct email address.

Comment: The problem is that it didn't send. I did check all folders and have re-verified that my email is correctly verified. I also have a mailbox rule set to automatically move all emails containing steam in the header to a separate folder.

Comment: Well good luck with Steam support. They usually investigate things before they get back to you, so hopefully they are looking into your issue right now!

Comment: Steam support was useless, took 4 days, and only reset my password which I could already do and did. They clearly didn't read the ticket info I provided because I clearly stated that.